# Listen for child process creation/fork

Tags: bash, shell, process, signals, fork

Say I have a process like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

node foo.js &
pid=$!
```

is there a way to listen to child processes that get created from pid?
I want to create a list of pids that get created/forked from pid.

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: Well, you can use `strace` for that, if you don't mind running your process under it.